Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatImageView' net Maui 8 after killing the app
I'm developing an Android app using Net Maui 8, I have a Page with 3 images, on first run everything works as expected, but the problem is when I kill the app and then reopen it then I got the error:

Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatImageView'

If I remove the 3 images from the xaml then no error is thrown, but if I leave one, no matter which one, the error is thrown.
The page is added as transient in the MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<ScanQrPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ScanQrPageViewModel>();

I would greatly appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue.

So, based on this answer I just wraped each one of my images inside a stack layout like
 <StackLayout>
     <Image
         Aspect="AspectFill"
         HeightRequest="{OnIdiom 80,
                                 Phone=50}"
         Source="{Binding SchoolLogo, TargetNullValue='school_icon'}"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         WidthRequest="{OnIdiom 80,
                                Phone=50}" />
 </StackLayout>

And now everything works as expected

I tried @salva answer and that did not help in my situation. I kept getting the same "'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatImageView'.'" message.
I was using the current "Microsoft.Maui.Controls" package of 8.0.80. Downgrading it to Version="8.0.72" was what fixed it for me.
Most of my images were in a frame, now in a border tag, others were suggesting it as a fix. But that gave me more of the same errors.

I have the same issue experince with it

System.ObjectDisposedException
Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatImageView'.

and I removed all
<ButtonImage />

That it has the same problem.
